# unable to launch swift from another directory in Ubuntu

Tags: swift, ubuntu-14.04

I am unable to launch swift terminal or unable to do swift build from any other directory (apart from ../swift/usr/bin ) in Ubuntu . When i am in swift folder (../swift/usr/bin) where i installed it, i am able to launch swift REPL but not from any other directory
I even exported the bin path to environment variable

```
export PATH=/home/vinit/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-24-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin:$PATH
```

I executed this command from bin directory. And checked it with

```
echo $PATH
```

I was getting

```
/home/vinit/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-24-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin:/home/vinit/.linuxbrew/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/vinit/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin
```

but when i executed the same (echo $PATH) from other directory , i am not getting swift in environment variable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the swift entry in PATH to disappear, I am guessing that you restarted the terminal after you exported PATH or had more than one terminal open at a time, and tried to work simultaneously. Try putting the export command in the .bashrc file in your home folder and open a new terminal.